# Windows Phone 8 Accelerometer

Tags: windows-phone-8, accelerometer

I'm trying to use the Accelerometer in my application but an error comes up and I have been trying to get around it. I'm not the best programmer but I'm trying to get better. the error is "accelerometer_CurrentValueChanged doesn't exist". How do I use this properly, many sites use this line of code and I'm wondering why it isn't working for me. I have all the API and I have the references that I am meant to have but it just wont work. What is it even there for? any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in your output view, you need to check in your .cs, if you have this methode.If you don't have this, you need to choice to delete property in your xaml or put the correct methode in your .cs.

Like this =>

```
void accelerometer_CurrentValueChanged(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> e)
        {
            //Do your job
        }
```

But please use your favorite web browser for do a little search before post in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
Accelerometer accelerometer;
public AccelerometerTest(){
accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
if (accelerometer != null)
{
    accelerometer.CurrentValueChanged += accelerometer_CurrentValueChanged;
    accelerometer.TimeBetweenUpdates = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
    accelerometer.Start();
}
} 
void accelerometer_CurrentValueChanged(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> e)
{
//do your code
}
```